# How can you save a playlist in YouTube's new interface?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a YouTube account and I saw a very nice playlist but unfortunately it is not well ordered. I would like to save that playlist and edit it.

Could someone tell me how this can be done (saving the playlist) in the new YouTube interface?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to clone a playlist yet as we could in the [previous interface](http://www.labnol.org/internet/copy-youtube-playlists/18483/), but if there is I'd love to find out ^_^

Answer (score 1):

## For the old (One Channel) design:

On the playlist page, click the "+ Save" button to save the playlist to your library as-is. A playlist saved like this will get updated as the original creator updates it. You can also clone the playlist by clicking the three dots > "Add all to..." button and adding all videos to a playlist you fully control.

The old design is currently available by appending `&disable_polymer=1` to the URL, or by using Internet Explorer. It may disappear in he future though.

[image: old design]

## For the new (Material) design

On the watch page, you can save the playlist by clicking the 3-line icon with the plus next to it.

[image: Watch page]

On the playlist page, you can save the playlist by clicking the very same icon in a different position.

[image: Playlist view]

Note that these options merely save the playlist to your library, they don't clone it for you to edit it. To clone playlists, you'll have to find a bookmarklet or an API program that basically iterates through all items of a playlist given playlist and creates a new playlist from your account. Creating a program like this is <s>left as exercise to the reader</s> out-of-scope for the Webapps Stackexchange and more something for StackOverflow. Though [this](https://ctrlq.org/youtube/playlists/) exists if you trust an unknown third party application to take over parts of your account.